# how to validate an image array in php

Tags: php, smarty

```
<input name= "p_image[]" type="file" id="p_image[]">
```

i need that user upload atleast one image and if it doesn't it show error..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the `count` of the array, and if it's equal to `0`, then throw an error:

```
<?php

   if(isset($_POST['p_image'])) { 
      if(!(count($_POST['p_image']))) {
          //throw error here...
      }
   } else {
     //throw another error here...
   }
?>
```

Comment: again same problem arise's when i upload one image it show error not submit the form

Comment: Isn't that what you asked for? Please clarify.

Comment: i want that when user upload one image it's submit the form

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

   if(!isset($_POST['p_image'])) { 

          //failure messgae

   }
?>
```